# add node to cluster using cmd in windows elasticsearch

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, cmd

How can I add nodes to same cluster using **cmd in windows**? 
There are commands to do that for linux. Is there a similar thing for windows? I tried searching, but I didn't find anything.
(Sorry if this seems really basic, I'm new to this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special command to "add nodes to same cluster". A node needs to be **started**, it has to have the **same `cluster.name`** value in `elasticsearch.yml` file and it needs to be able to contact the other nodes, either via multicasting (`discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true` which is also the default) or unicasting (`discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2:port"]`).

I strongly suggest that, if you want to use Elasticsearch, to at least read some of the basics, as it seems you haven't. For example, start with https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/modules-discovery.html.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm following. I'm still at their "Getting Started" section though. Sorry for my wrong terminology.